# What is a useful "transfer large things" method/medium?

Tags: hardware, storage, hard-drive, file-transfer, usb-flash-drive

Other than through the network, what does everyone use for transferring things like system images or very large files?

For example, external case+hard drive like a myBook. Or, extremely large usb/flash drive. I've been using a hard drive (or multiple various hard drives) in this:[external SATA](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817153071)

But, not everything has SATA, and USB seems really slow with it. Plus, having to always plug in the power cable is a hassle, and it's pretty loose in the slot so if you bump it, it can disconnect.

Comment: Absent concrete requirements this question is unanswerable - there are a nearly infinite number of ways to get data from machine A to machine B, depending on physical distance, available interfaces, the number of cats in the area (a real concern with [IP over Avian Carriers!](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1149)), etc.

Comment: Neither USB nor Firewire external hard-drives I've used need a power cord. They're both powered over the bus.

Comment: You may wish to consider RFC 1149 -> http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1149

Answer (score 7):

[Fill a station-wagon full of tapes and drive it down a freeway.](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Andrew_S._Tanenbaum#Sourced)

Comment: If it's on-premises transfer, put the tapes into a weighted companion cube and use the Aperture Science Pneumatic Diversity Tube system: http://half-life.wikia.com/index.php?title=Aperture_Science_Pneumatic_Diversity_Vent&image=Diversity_vent_diag-jpg

Comment: There's always the **[Dirty Things With Netcat](http://serverfault.com/a/51605/16732)** Method

Comment: @cjc, what happens if the weighted companion cube gets...accidentially...incinerated? I hope you have backups.

Answer (score 2):

I find the fastest way is to transfer the files over Ethernet.  With both systems connected to the same LAN of course.  Otherwise I burn the files to a DVD or DL-DVD.

Answer (score 1):

I think most people here use network drives that lead to NAS. To move very large files between two machines on a unix-variant you can use Rsync.

Answer (score 0):

USB 3 devices seem to be the answer for me.  terabyte size transfers now go from days to hours.