# How to Migrate Logical Volume Manager (LVM) Configuration to a New Drive

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lvm

We have a *Ubuntu 20.04 Server Edition* installation that was borked upgrading to *22.04* and it doesn't boot. The `root` partition is on a old physical drive, installed on a disk partition (e.g. `sda3`).  The system setup is that we use LVM to manage the other phsyical drives, but importantly the **root partition is not on LVM**.

As the system physical disk is old, we'd like to perform a fresh installation of *Ubuntu* on a brand new SSD.  Under any other circumstances we would clone the drive using `dd`, but in this instance we would like to migrate just the LVM configuration from the old system disk to a new *Ubuntu* installation on a fresh disk.

How can we migrate an existing LVM configuration into a new system installation on a new drive?

---

#### Notes

- I can still access the existing root partition using a LiveCD/USB however the system doesn't boot and I'd prefer not to fix it.
- I have considered simply copying `/etc/lvm` but not sure if there are additional changes required.
- I am aware of the `vgchange`, `vgexport` and `vgimport` commands, however my limited understanding suggests that I need a working system to run these commands.

Answer (score 0):

Busted OS distro but existing data implies creating a new OS instance, then block level restore data, and copy over select data files still remaining.  Other options are possible depending on what backups exist; restores are a choose your own adventure where you need to think about the way forward.

Start installing the new host. Recommend root fs on LVM, based on other questions here about it filling up and needing to do some tricky partitioning.

### LVM metadata

Backups of metadata in /etc/lvm/backup/  and /etc/lvm/archive/ are text files, logging all sorts of useful things: device WWN, PV name and ID, LV name ID and extent map, VG name and ID. Archive this, perhaps all of /etc, as a part of a host level backup of the old instance.  However LVM operates from on-disk metadata. In the simple case VGs do not need this exact metadata to be imported or rebuilt.

### Keep PVs or not

Decide whether to detach and reuse the disks from the old instance or not. Could be easy to swing over with virtual or SAN storage. Or could be not what you want to do, such as with old physical disks where you want to accomplish a storage migration.

### Rescue mode

Either way, on the old host boot some rescue distro where you can do things to LVM.  Run the commands `pvs; vgs; lvs;`  to get a summary of LVM on the system.  `vgimportdevices --all; pvscan --cache`  should make PVs known to the system if they are not already. (In more complex recovery scenarios where LVM is missing something or is corrupted, this is where metadata backups are useful.)

### Reusing disks

For the reuse disks option, it is prudent to deactivate and export the VG, so the old system will not attempt to use it. Examples you might see of this are under the use case of [moving a VG to another system](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/configuring_and_managing_logical_volumes/managing-lvm-volume-groups_configuring-and-managing-logical-volumes#proc_moving-volume-group-to-another-system-managing-lvm-volume-groups).

I have not provided examples of LVM arguments that will be different for you: VG, LV, PV, block devices. Read the documentation for usage details.

```
# Old host in rescue mode
umount
vgchange -an
vgexport 
# Move disks to other system
# New host
vgimportdevices --all
vgimport
vgchange -ay
```

### Not reusing disks

If swinging over disks is inconvenient, or you want to change VG or LV configuration, rebuilding VG then restoring data is an option.

Copying over the data can be done at the block level, which can be fast compared to file level restore. Important: copy the LVs, not the lower level PVs. If you have IP networking, the copy can be done via [dd through  ssh and/or netcat](https://serverfault.com/q/51567/241174).

```
# Old host in rescue mode
vgchange -ay
umount
# snapshots optionally can capture a point in time while the origin is still in use
# lvcreate --snapshot

# New host
vgcreate 
# be sure LVs are at least as large as the old LVs
lvcreate
# Old host in rescue mode
dd if=/dev/vg/lv | gzip | ssh root@target 'gzip -d | dd of=/dev/vg/lv'
```

### pvmove

If both old and new disks can be attached to the new host, the VG can be imported as is but then migrated to new PVs. Useful tool, either now during recovery, or in future storage migrations.

Follow the above reusing disks procedure to import the VGs.

```
vgextend # new PV
pvmove # old PV
vgreduce --all  # empty old PVs
```

### Validate applications function

With a new OS install and post storage migration, a check things function is a good idea.

Edit /etc/fstab and add the migrated volumes. Install and update applications.  Reboot. Spot check applications start and do what they should.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. I just want to clarify a key points. 1) The LVM metadata is stored on disk, so does it matter if the disks on the old system are exported at all? Do you *need* to deactivate them for them to be imported into a new system? 2) Under your rescue mode commands, it appears that these commands will help any system recognise an LVM.  Can that approach also be used to migrate an existing /etc/lvm to a new system and running the same commands with a new partition?

Comment: For context, I think you've my answered my question just seeking some clarification before I try it and accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Deactivating and exporting adds safety in the reuse PVs use case, to prevent auto activating and causing a mess prior to your intentional  vgimport.  Config files in  /etc/lvm control advanced features, and the metadata backups help recovery when LVM is very broken.  Neither are strictly necessary for your simple use case.  If you want to experience a restore in hard mode, maybe intentionally corrupt the PV and/or LV on disk, like by editing their IDs. Fixed by a vgcfgrestore  to put it back on the devices in the backup file.

Comment: Thanks John - I will follow your advice, try it and report back.